# My Rails application is only giving me a blank screen, with no HTML at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app that I haven't worked with in a month or so. I just tried to pull it up, and it is giving me only a blank screen. I am running in dev mode, and monitoring the log. The log shows that everything is OK, in that it is processing the appropriate controller and views.

The nginx log shows no errors. How can I troubleshoot what is happening? This is a Rails 3.0.9 application.

This appears to be a Passenger issue. Unfortunately, Passenger isn't writing any errors that I can see in the logs. I'm getting 200's from nginx also. I have never see something return no HTML at all without errors before.

Update:  This is the output from curl -I http://mcp.com (note that I have mcp.com aliased to localhost)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.7
ETag: "17676b3c3d3b322365c8d431f62f944b"
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-Runtime: 9.088870
Set-Cookie: _mcp5_session=BAh7CCIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iMVNGRHZ1WVNLZFRIeTh1Sm1lNytyVEU3TkhmQU1pVWZSdXBud2htcFRHSGs9IhRlbnRyeV9zdWJkb21haW4iACIPc2Vzc2lvbl9pZCIlMjA1NGIxNTRmN2M2NTQyNDU1ZTVmZjExYzRjNDhlMTY%3D--c3d21d4bb07a4989243b655aff3d49863d8c81f7; domain=.mcp.com; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Server: nginx/1.1.4 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.7 (mod_rails/mod_rack)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code from the respective part (or parts, but choosing a single instance would be a better start) that you know are failing?

Comment: How about starting in dev mode with Webrick or Thin as webserver, and look if that works well.

Comment: Yep, that works like a champ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually that's caused by an exception in production mode, so to see it in dev mode might be an artifact of your server. Investigate if your launcher, like Passenger, is working correctly or not.

If `script/console` or `rails console` starts up okay, and you can access it through `script/server` or `rails server` then you should be able to narrow it down to the web server level.

Comment: console starts fine. It is definitely a Passenger issue. I don't know where Passenger logs to though. It doesn't log to the default nginx log.

Comment: First step is to always at least try upgrading and/or resinstalling Passenger.

Comment: I recompiled and installed, and no dice.

Comment: You need to narrow it down somehow. Does it affect all pages of your app? All apps? A new bare-bones Rails app? Have a look with `curl -I` to be sure you're getting something back.

Comment: I added the curl response above. It's like Passenger is just not returning XML. The Rails log messages are identical to what they'd be if it was working.